# Fetching the highest number in a column

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating a website and I need to get the highest number in a column. What would be the INSERT... be. For example INSERT * FROM $database. You know what I mean. What would that be? By the way the column name is "id" if that helps.

Comment: Please find some SQL tutorial first

Comment: Is id not auto increment?

Answer (score 2):

To get the highest number, use the [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) function:

```
SELECT MAX(id) id FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```